# Bootstrap 5 change font size through media queries

Tags: bootstrap-5

I want to reduce the font size in small screens so I modify the default font size in pixels so that the font size rem value in paragraph automatically adapts.

```
body {
    font-family: 'Work Sans', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.1rem;     
    line-height: 1.3rem;   
}

 ...

@media (min-width: 576px) {
    :root {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    :root {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

It seems to work but I'm new to Bootstrap 5 and I'm not sure if it's the way to go.
Is there another way to do it ?

Comment: Does it work? Then do it. There are always multiple ways to achieve something, go with what works best for you.

Comment: Yes I know, but as I said I'm new with Bootstrap and I don't want to use it in a way that might have bad after effect in a long run.

Answer (score 1):

You can update font size using css variables.

```
body {
    --bs-body-font-size: 12px;
}
@media(min-width:991px){
    body {
        --bs-body-font-size: 15px;
    }
}
@media(min-width:1400px){
    body {
        --bs-body-font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```